# How to increment the step value by two

Tags: jquery

I have an array like this

```
arr=["rose","AA","lotus","BB","Jasmine","CC",tulip,"DD"];

$.each(arr, function(topics,i){
             document.write(topics);
             document.write(i);           

            })
```

I want something to be printed like
rose-AA
lotus-BB
Jasmine-CC
tuplic-DD

How to increment the index by 1 while using the .each? I tried to use topics++ but it never worked.

Comment: Maybe you don't want `each` then?

Comment: Agreed. I think that a for loop would work

Answer (score 1):

Try a simple for loop.

```
arr=["rose","AA","lotus","BB","Jasmine","CC","tulip","DD"];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2) {
   document.write(arr[i] + "-" + arr[i+1] + ' ');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, such a silly thing, I didnt think properly.

Comment: That's just too much jQuery thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

Use simple for loop for iteration.( I am assuming that length of arr always going to be even number)

```
for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i = i+2){
         document.write(arr[i]+"-"+arr[i+1] + " ");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var arr = ["rose", "AA", "lotus", "BB", "Jasmine", "CC", "tulip", "DD"];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
        document.write(arr[i] + "-" + arr[i + 1] + ' ');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the odd indices:

```
$.each(arr, function(topics, i){
  if ((topics % 2) == 0) {
    document.write(topics);
    document.write(i);           
  }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/VT9tT/

Comment: @Vega: Why do you need to use a simple loop when you can do it with a convenient method?

Comment: @Vega: Yes, it's convenient for iterating an array, that's the entire purpose for its existance. If you don't think that its convenient, then just don't use it. May I please use it if I like to?

Comment: I am sorry, If that was offensive. I was just sharing my thought.